# Program will not compare the real answer to the players answer

Tags: variables, python-3.x

When I run the program, I will put in the correct answer but it will always mark it as wrong:

> (10, '+', 2)
>   12
>   ...
>   Wrong answer, the answer was 12 !

Here is the section of code which is wrong:

```
Player_answer = input()
print ("...")
time.sleep (0.5)

if operation==("+"): #check answer
    answer = num1+num2  #This works out the real answer

    if Player_answer == answer:  #This works out if the player is correct
        print("That's the correct answer")
        score = score + 1
    else:
        print("Wrong answer, the answer was",answer,"!")

if operation==("*"):
    answer = num1*num2

    if Player_answer == answer:
        print("That's the correct answer")
        score = score + 1
    else:
        print("Wrong answer, the answer was",answer,"!")

elif operation==("-"):
    answer = num1-num2

    if Player_answer == answer:
        print("That's the correct answer")
        score = score + 1
    else:
        print("Wrong answer, the answer was",answer,"!")
```

Comment: try `if  int(Player_answer) == answer`

Comment: check the type of answer you are getting from player. Check out with adding print type(Player_answer)

Answer (score 0):

By default, `input()` returns a string. So, even if you type in 12, `Player_input` is `"12"` (a string). To make `Player_input` an `int`eger, simply type `Player_input = int(Player_input)`. The `int()` function takes any data value, and attempts to convert it to an integer. However, if it cannot convert, such as trying to convert `"not num"`, it will raise a `ValueError` To prevent this, you can wrap it in a `try/except` statement.